# How do append two decimal point after the amount

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I try below value to convert two decimal point with decimal style.please refer below example.

```
    --->1 expected 1.00
    --->1. expected 1.00
    ---->1.0 expected 1.00
    --->1.01 expected 1.01
    --->1235.06 expected 1,235.06
    --->12356.36 expected 12,356.36 
   ---->12356.0 expected 12,356.00
   --->12356. expected 12356.00
```

I try below code but it'll not work form me.please help me for this.

```
   NSNumberFormatter *doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];

    [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces setPaddingPosition:NSNumberFormatterPadAfterSuffix];

    [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces setFormatWidth:2];

    [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

    doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces.positiveFormat = @"0.##";

    NSNumber *myValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.01];

    NSNumber *myValue1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0];

    NSNumber *myValue2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.];

    NSNumber *myValue3 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:1];

    NSLog(@" [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces stringFromNumber:myValue] :%@", [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces stringFromNumber:myValue]);

    NSLog(@" [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces stringFromNumber:myValue] :%@", [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces stringFromNumber:myValue1]);

    NSLog(@" [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces stringFromNumber:myValue] :%@", [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces stringFromNumber:myValue2]);

    NSLog(@" [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces stringFromNumber:myValue] :%@", [doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces stringFromNumber:myValue3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.discountPriceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Rs %.2f",_productDetails.discountprice];
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the number of decimal places you need to set the *minimum* fractional digits as well as the maximum as you have done - set these both to `2` in your case. Also you need to set the property for using a thousand separator as that is not the default for `NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle`. The following, written using property style setting, should produce what you wish:

```
doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces.maximumFractionDigits = 2;
doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces.minimumFractionDigits = 2;
doubleValueWithMaxTwoDecimalPlaces.hasThousandSeparators = YES;
```

(The thousand separator used will be the one appropriate for the current locale, if you always require a comma you should set that as well.)

HTH